# calculate $\oint_{|z|=1}z^{2018}e^{\frac{1}{z}}\sin\frac{1}{z}\text{dz}$

Tags: complex-analysis, contour-integration, residue-calculus

calculate $\oint_{|z|=1}z^{2018}e^{\frac{1}{z}}\sin\frac{1}{z}\text{dz}$
my try:

$
\begin{array}{c}
\oint_{|z|=1}z^{2018}e^{\frac{1}{z}}\sin\frac{1}{z}\text{dz}\\
\oint_{|z|=1}z^{2018}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)^{n}}{n!}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(\frac{1}{z}i\right)^{n}-\left(-\frac{1}{z}i\right)^{n}}{2in!}\text{dz}\\
\oint_{|z|=1}z^{2018}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-n}}{n!}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(-zi\right)^{-n}-\left(zi\right)^{-n}}{2in!}\text{dz}\\
\oint_{|z|=1}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-n+2018}}{n!}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(-zi\right)^{-n}-\left(zi\right)^{-n}}{2in!}\text{dz}\\
\oint_{|z|=1}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-n+2018}}{n!}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(-zi\right)^{-n}-\left(zi\right)^{-n}}{2in!}\text{dz}\\
{\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-n+2018}}{n!}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(-zi\right)^{-n}-\left(zi\right)^{-n}}{2in!}\text{}\\
{\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-n+2018}}{n!}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(z\right)^{-n}(-i)^{-n}-\left(z\right)^{-n}(i)^{n}}{2in!}\text{}\\
{\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-2n+2018}\left((-i)^{-n}-i^{n}\right)}{2i(n!)^{2}}\text{}\\
-2n+2018=-1\\
n\notin\mathbb{N}\\
{\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-2n+2018}\left((-i)^{-n}-i^{n}\right)}{2i(n!)^{2}}=0
\end{array}$

$\oint_{|z|=1}z^{2018}e^{\frac{1}{z}}\sin\frac{1}{z}\text{dz}=0$
edit: I took the advise in the comment now I get:
$
{\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-n+2018}}{n!}{\displaystyle \mathop{\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{\left(z\right)^{-k}(-i)^{-k}-\left(z\right)^{-k}(i)^{k}}{2ik!}\text{}\\{\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{0}^{\infty}}}\frac{z^{-n-k+2018}\left((-i)^{-k}-i^{k}\right)}{2i(n!)(k!)}\text{}\\-n-k+2018=-1\\n+k=2019\\{\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{n+k=2019;n,k=0}}}\frac{z^{-n-k+2018}\left((-i)^{-k}-i^{k}\right)}{2i(n!)(k!)}$
which I don't know to sum

${\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{k=0}^{2019}}}\frac{z^{-1}\left((-i)^{-k}-i^{k}\right)}{2i((2019-k)!)(k!)}={\displaystyle \mathop{Res\sum_{k=0}^{2019}}}\frac{\left((-i)^{-k}-i^{k}\right)}{2i((2019-k)!)(k!)}$

Comment: I think we need to use different indices for the summations.  The first summation is $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{z^{-n}}{n!}.$  The second summation can be in terms of $k$ or anything other than $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If inside the unit disc is too nasty, we can try to move it to outside the unit disc.  In other words, integrate it on the other side of the Riemann sphere using the chart $w=\frac1z$.

So, with $w=\frac1z$, the unit circle $\lvert z\rvert=1$ is $\lvert w\rvert=1$, in the **opposite** direction.  Everything else is just what you expect:
$$
\int_{S^1}z^{2018}\exp(z^{-1})\sin(z^{-1})\,\mathrm{d}z
=-\int_{S^1}w^{-2018}\exp(w)\sin(w)\cdot -w^{-2}\,\mathrm{d}w.
$$
Now you can calculate the RHS much more readily: $\exp(w)\sin(w)$ is holomophic and we have
$$
\exp(w)\sin(w)=\frac1{2i}\left[\exp((1+i)w)-\exp((1-i)w)\right]
$$
so
\begin{align*}
&=\frac{1}{2i}\int_{S^1}\frac{\exp((1+i)w)-\exp((1-i)w)}{w^{2020}}\,\mathrm{d}w
\\
&=\pi\cdot\text{coefficient of }w^{2019}\text{ in }\big[\exp((1+i)w)-\exp((1-i)w)\big]\\
&=\pi\frac{(1+i)^{2019}-(1-i)^{2019}}{2019!}
\end{align*}
and it is not hard to calculate powers of $1\pm i$ using $(1\pm i)/\sqrt{2}$ is an 8-th root of unity.